# set a demand and supply curve for the model tragedy of the commons in the case of an overfished pond

Tags: netlogo

I am new at net logo and I want to write a model based on tragedy of the commons in the case of an overfished pond. The purpose is to find an equilibrium between fishers and fishes based on an economic model with demand and supply. If there are less fishers, more fishes will be in the pond, then after a certain time (ticks) the number of fishers increases and less fishes will be in the pond. Maybe set like a number of fishes per day that can be fished. Thus, the solution is to find a convenient number of fishers as the fishes can still reproduce. I want to have a box in the interface where I can type in a number and see what happens with the number of fishes.

I have no idea how to set this up. I hope to hear from you :)

I started with this code:

```
breed [fishers fisher]

breed [fishes fish]


to setup 

  clear-all

  reset-ticks

   ask patches [set pcolor blue ]     ;; lake/pond in form of a rectangle in color 

   ask patches [ if pxcor > 8  [ set pcolor green ]]

   ask patches [ if pycor > 8  [ set pcolor green ]]

   ask patches [ if pycor < -8 [ set pcolor green ]]

   ask patches [ if pxcor < -8 [ set pcolor green ]]    

  ask one-of patches with [ pcolor = blue ] [ sprout 20 [set shape "fish" set color pink set size 1.5 ]] ;; creates fishes

  ask one-of patches with [ pcolor = green ] [ sprout 2 [set shape "person" set color black set size 3 ] ]  ;; creates fishers


end

to go

  tick

  ;;fishes

  ask turtles with [ shape = "fish" and color = pink ]  

  [ right random 360 forward 1  

    if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = green [ right 180 fd 1 ]]



  ;; fishers  

  ask turtles with [ shape = "person" and color = black] 

  [;right random 360 forward 1


  if any? patches with [pcolor = blue]

     [set heading towards one-of patches with [pcolor = blue] forward 1]


     if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = blue [ right 180 fd 2 ]]



   ask turtles with [shape = "person" and color = black] 

    [if any? turtles with [shape = "fish" and color = pink] in-radius 2

    [ask turtles with [shape = "fish" and color = pink] in-radius 2  [die]]]


end
```

Comment: Are the bits like `breed [fishes fish]` and `ask turtles with [ shape = "person" and color = black]` code? If so, could you edit your post to better distinguish what is and is not code?

Comment: To create a code block, you can indent the text four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you look through existing models in the Netlogo library (Wolf-sheep-predation model may help). You roughly have the right idea in your current code, but you should look at other models to improve. You've already set your different breeds of turtles, but you should also set up their respective shapes under 'setup'. This would help you a great deal later - instead of calling for

```
ask turtles with [ shape = "fish"...]
```

you can simply

```
ask fishes [do sth...]
```

For that 'box at the interface', you can have a slider at the interface determining the number of fishers you want your run to start with. With another slider, you can set the fishing pressure in your simulated run (i.e. how many fish each fisher will catch) and I suppose you can also consider how this changes when population of fish decreases.

Finally, for a model like yours, you can observe the supply and demand trend by plotting the curves of no. of fishers over time and no. of fishes over time. Again, look at the wolf-sheep-predation model to have an idea of how to do this.

I can't give you more than this I'm afraid since I'm no pro myself but hope this helps a little. Hope someone else would be able to give you a clearer idea.